# How to copy array of objects without reference?

Tags: javascript

i need to copy array of objects without reference. I tried

```
newarr = arr.slice();
newarr = [...arr]];
```

But both of them have reference to object so when i change them in newarr it changes in arr aswell.

Comment: `newarr = arr.map(obj => ({...obj}))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: newarr = arr.map(obj => ({...obj})) works, do you know performace of this method?

Comment: @JirkaKastan: If they have nested objects, it will not clone them.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));` should work ;)

Comment: @alfasin This is a good method, although definitely worth mentioning its limitations. Doesn't work if there are circular references, will drop any methods/functions, converts `date`s to `string`s, etc.